# How can I fix an IE6-8 delay when loading a page? jQuery code and development site included inside post

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently have been throwing together a client site and am starting to notice long frozen delays in IE6-8.

So I went back and rewrote a lot of it, but I'm still having trouble narrowing down the problem(s).

Here's what I have currently.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* header slideshow */

var slide_pos = 0;

var slide_len = $("#slideshow li").size() - 1;

slide_int = setInterval(function() {

    slide_cur = $("#slideshow li:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
    slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

    slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));

    slide_cur = $("#slideshow li:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
    slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

}, 5000);


/* left_menu */

$('#left_menu li').hover(function(){

    var left_menu_pos = $(this).position();

    $('> .sub-menu:first', this).show();

}, function(){

    $('> .sub-menu:first', this).hide();

});


/* search form */

$('#search_input').focus(function(){

    if($(this).attr('placeholder') == $(this).val()){

        $(this).val('');

    }

}, function(){

    if($(this).val() == ''){

        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));

    }

});


/* fancybox declarations */

$('.sidebar_thumb a').fancybox({cyclic:true});

</script>
```

**Here's the updated code to match Peeter's suggestions.  Still having issues though.  Any suggestions?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* header slideshow */

var slide_pos = 0;

var slide_len = $('#slideshow').find('li').size() - 1;

(function slide_int(){

    slide_cur = $('#slideshow').find('li').eq(slide_pos);
    slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

    slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));

    slide_cur = $('#slideshow').find('li').eq(slide_pos);
    slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

    setTimeout(slide_int, 5000);

}());


/* left_menu */

$('#left_menu').find('li').mouseover(function(){

    var left_menu_pos = $(this).position();

    $(this).find('.sub-menu:first').show();

}).mouseout(function(){

    $(this).find('.sub-menu:first').hide();

});

/* search form */

$('#search_input').focus(function(){

    if($(this).attr('placeholder') == $(this).val()){

        $(this).val('');

    }

}, function(){

    if($(this).val() == ''){

        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));

    }

});


/* fancybox declarations */

$('.sidebar_thumb a').fancybox({cyclic:true});
</script>
```

Now my question is, could the setInterval be waiting to start, could it be that the #left_menu has about 50 list items in it, or do I just plain sucking at writing code?

Comment: I just did a quick test and the 3 main browsers were all very similar. (In fact FF was slightly worst, with Chrome slightly best) What sort of delay are you experiencing?

Comment: IE freezes for a few seconds when the page loads.  I just updated the javascript to match Peeter's suggestions.  It's in the original post.

Comment: It all boiled down to the filters being applied in the FancyBox CSS file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function selfExecutingTimeout(){

    console.log('Do stuff');

    setTimeout(selfExecutingTimeout, 5000);
}());
```

This is what I'd try instead of the setInterval. The problem with setInterval is that it'll continue calling your function regardless if it has actually finished. So if your animation takes longer then 5 seconds, setInterval will call it again regardless.

That pattern will call the function in 5 seconds after it has finished. So if your animation takes longer then 5 seconds it wont matter.

I'm not saying this is the root cause of your problem, but it wouldn't hurt to change that part :P

Ontop of that I'd change

```
$('#left_menu li')
```

to

```
$('#left_menu').find("li")
```

as it'll be changed to that in the core anyway.

Also change this

```
$('> .sub-menu:first', this)
```

to

```
$(this).find('.sub-menu:first')
```

Although I'd speculate that the problem lies in the Google calendar plugin you have there. It seems like once it starts to load, IE hangs till it's done.

Comment: I updated the code to match yours, still having issues though :(  It's in the original post.

Comment: I actually just pinpointed the issues to FancyBox.  There were many progid filters being applied via CSS so I just removed them.

This has been a pain in the A.  Thanks for the help though!  Peeter your code did increase the speed a bit, so have a checkmark!